# How can I reinstall Windows 7 (w/ install DVD) with minimal (or hopeful no) impact on installed programs?

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-restore

I know that Windows 8 has a Refresh option.

Is there anything like that for Windows 7 (64 b)

I have the original install CD (I think!).

I'm getting weird data-related errors like:

- ChdkDsk errors and 88K in Bad Sectors
- SFC shows some files could not be repaired (about 10 files)
- Picasa is freezing everytime I try to copy a file

I have tried:

- Backed up my primary Win drive (c:)
- System Restore to oldest version (about 3 weeks). No Love.

I have:

- Windows 7 Repair DVD I create for this computer.
- Windows Restore I created for a different Windows 7 computer (also 64bit)
- Another Windows 7 DVD that is either a Win 7 install or a Windows 7 Restore (it's a DVD I created and it just says Windows 7 $ThisComputer.
- I do have a 2 month old backup that might help, but I really don't want to restore all of that stuff and I know restoring system files is tricky b/c Windows prevents copying over system files (for security reasons)

Comment: Most of those errors won't be fixed by installing Windows again.  There is no `Refresh` feature within Windows 7. You can do an [in-place upgrade](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/is-in-place-upgrade-available-to-repair-windows-7/7b338507-0ff8-4209-b1ee-354ad976c79c), which is the closest thing, but its unlikely to solve your major problem your HDD is failing.  You can also use the `Repair` option but that requires your `component store` ( i.e. `WinSxS` ) not be corrupt.

Comment: You seem to have a failing hard drive. Reinstall will not fix that. Clone the drive to a new good one, then do the in-place upgrade which will retain programs and settings.

Comment: @Dan, I used the Samsung Magician SSD software to check the SSD and it says it was in good or excellent condition. Found only 88K in bad sectors. How would I know if it truly was going bad?

BTW, I have not gotten NEW chkdsk errors in the last few days.

Comment: @Ramhound  Please do post that as an Answer and I'll accept (unless a better answer comes along, which I doubt)
So, as long as I don't have corrupt files in C:\Windows\winsxs\ directory I can try the Repair option?

Comment: @ClayNichols - There are already questions asking about in-place upgrades of Windows 7 and existing answers how to accomplish it.  The problem you will find is you actually do have a corrupt component store since SFC failed.  I suppose you can use a different `WinSxS` source instead which would solve the corruption.  The real problem is even if you install Windows again your disk is still failing, us numerous bad sectors on it, and its only a matter of time before system files are moved to other bad sectors.

Comment: @ClayNichols - It seems to me that 88K sectors is enough sectors that have failed, that I would RMA the drive, but that's me personally.